# How to insert data to another table with multiples rows to a single row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've been stuck for a couple of days for this problem, hope someone can give me an idea. Thank you in advance.

My concern is that I want to insert data from `table2` to `table1`. In `table2` it is in rows (day1 to day2), and I want to insert in table1 as a single row per id.

id#: 01 has day1 and day2 in table2.

[Please refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2OKH.png)

Comment: What is db version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping someone will provide a neater solution for you, as I am interested in seeing it too. The only way I can solve the problem is by making an initial insert on the summed data and then updating the individual stats:

```
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
ID INT,
Name CHAR,
Gender CHAR,
Dt DATE,
OvertimeMins INT,
UndertimeMins INT,
WorkMins INT
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 (ID, Name, Gender, DT, OvertimeMins, UndertimeMins, WorkMins) SELECT 01, 'A', 'M', '28 Jul 2017', 30, 0, 240
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 (ID, Name, Gender, DT, OvertimeMins, UndertimeMins, WorkMins) SELECT 01, 'A', 'M', '29 Jul 2017', 60, 0, 240


DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Name CHAR,
    Gender CHAR,
    TotalOtMins INT,
    TotalUTMins INT,
    TotalWorkMins INT,
    Day1OTMins INT,
    Day1UTMIns INT,
    Day1WorkMIns INT,
    Day2OTMins INT,
    Day2UTMIns INT,
    Day2WorkMIns INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
(ID, Name, Gender, TotalOtMins, TotalUTMins, TotalWorkMins)
SELECT  ID, MIN(Name), MIN(Gender), SUM(OvertimeMins), SUM(UndertimeMins), Sum(WorkMins)
FROM @TABLE2
GROUP BY ID

UPDATE T1
SET Day1OTMins = Day1.OvertimeMins,
    Day1UTMins = Day1.UndertimeMins,
    Day1WorkMIns = Day1.WorkMins,
    Day2OTMins = Day2.OvertimeMins,
    Day2UTMIns = Day2.UndertimeMins,
    Day2WorkMIns = Day2.WorkMins
FROM @Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 OvertimeMIns, UndertimeMins, WorkMins
    FROM @Table2
    WHERE ID = T1.ID
    ORDER BY Dt ASC
) as Day1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 OvertimeMIns, UndertimeMins, WorkMins
    FROM @Table2
    WHERE ID = T1.ID
    ORDER BY Dt DESC
) as Day2

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
```

Comment: Hi, I have an additional query, in below code, could it be possible to loop the number of days? what if I have day1 to day31. my concern is to make the code short.  "UPDATE T1
SET Day1OTMins = Day1.OvertimeMins,
    Day1UTMins = Day1.UndertimeMins,
    Day1WorkMIns = Day1.WorkMins,
    Day2OTMins = Day2.OvertimeMins,
    Day2UTMIns = Day2.UndertimeMins,
    Day2WorkMIns = Day2.WorkMins
FROM @Table1 T1"

Answer (score 0):

```
;with sum_cte (id, name, gender, TotalOTMinis, TotalUTMins, TotalWorkMins)
as(
   select id, name, gender, sum(OvertimeMins), sum(UndertimeMins), sum(WorkMins) group by id
),
day1_cte (rownum, id, day1OTMins, day1UTMins, day1WrokMins)
as(
  select row_number() (over order by date) as rownum,id, OvertimeMins, UndertimeMins, WorkMins from table2 where rownum=1
),
day2_cte (rownum, id, day2OTMins, day2UTMins, day2WrokMins)
as(
select row_number() (over order by date) as rownum,id, OvertimeMins, UndertimeMins, WorkMins from table2 where rownum=2
)
insert into table1
select sum_cte.id, name, gender, TotalOTMinis, TotalUTMins, TotalWorkMins, day1OTMins, day1UTMins, day1WrokMins ,day2OTMins, day2UTMins, day2WrokMins
from sum_cte inner join day1_cte on sum_cte.id = day1_cte.id
inner join day2_cte on sum_cte.id = day2_cte
```